Disable Cmd + Hover to jump to definition in VSCode on macOS
In VSCode, whenever the Cmd key is down and I hover over a function definition, the editor automatically jumps to that definition. This incredibly annoying since I might press Cmd whenever I want to copy and paste some text, and then the editor will switch to another file.
Any idea how to disable this behaviour? All I can find is information about disabling Cmd+Click but nothing Cmd+Hover.
Edit:
This is an example of it. I press Cmd and move the cursor over the send keyword (in client.send) without clicking. This makes VSCode follow the link. And in that file the cursor ends up over another keyword which is then followed again, even though I didn't click on anything.

"edit.action.goto" commands

"go to" commands



Could you show a gif of what exactly you mean? I don't think hovering is supposed to cause actions like jumping to definition

I've just attached a video of it. I also don't think it should be doing this.

Show also a screenshot of all bindings for editor.action.goto search. Also check similar "Go to" ones if there's no weird keybind.

I've attached the bindings to the question although I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong here

Does this method disable this behavior? Note that this isn't supposed to happen without clicking on the function-name, so uninstalling VSCode and re-install might return it to the default behavior.

Do the automated clicks happen with anything else? Let's say you hold Cmd and hover an editor/file tab that isn't active, does it switch the file? If so, could it be some external hotkey software that holds LMB when you hold Cmd?

@harrymc, that method didn't help unfortunately, and I've just tried reinstalling VSCode which also didn't change anything

@Destroy666, no it only does this when hovering over the source code, specifically with TypeScript, although that's the only language I tried

There is a setting called "TypeScript: Prefer Go To Source Definition", see if it's checked and if so then try to uncheck it.

What's the VSCode version? Try installing VSCodium and check if it's ok there.

The bug report
Go To Source Definition feedback thread #49003
has
this answer
by the poster andrewbranch:

As of today’s VS Code Nightly, you can enable a setting that replaces
Go To Definition with Go To Source Definition, allowing you to
ctrl/⌘-click to trigger it. If source definitions cannot be retrieved,
it falls back to Go To Definition. Since this addresses the only piece
of feedback I’ve consistently received, I’m going to close this issue.
Thanks everyone!


In other words, this sets the Source Definition to be the
first attempt, with fallback to the type definition only if the
source definition cannot be found.
Check to see if the setting of
"TypeScript: Prefer Go To Source Definition"
is indeed checked on your side, and if so then try to uncheck it.

This mentions regular Ctrl + click, not Ctrl + hover
